# Can't find fault with rejected Xamarin app from iOS crash log from review

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, logging, xamarin.ios

I have a simple app developed on a Mac with Xamarin that runs fine locally (device and simulator) but has been rejected from the store as it crashes on start-up. The previous version of the app passed review (somehow) but crashed on startup for all users.

I have symbolicated the log but am none the wiser! Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
(15D60)","incident_id":"3D902E28-01E5-4AEF-82E6-26F7279BD1D0","name":"LexEAT.iOS"}
Incident Identifier: 3D902E28-01E5-4AEF-82E6-26F7279BD1D0
CrashReporter Key:   88d01bc8f6b5268e892877cbd5c292bb8f53ad2b
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             LexEAT.iOS [13178]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/30F4C650-51BE-46F8-B606-53046653486B/LexEAT.iOS.app/LexEAT.iOS
Identifier:          com.sentooit.lexeat
Version:             2.11 (2.11)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.sentooit.lexeat [4901]


Date/Time:           2018-03-03 17:18:20.5718 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-03-03 17:18:20.4297 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001842f82e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018440d2f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184267060 __abort + 152
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184266fc8 __abort + 0
4   LexEAT.iOS                      0x000000010370a8fc print_callback(char const*, int) + 16263420 (runtime.m:1211)
5   LexEAT.iOS                      0x0000000103701fe4 monoeg_g_log + 16228324 (goutput.c:125)
6   LexEAT.iOS                      0x000000010359e84c load_aot_module + 14772300 (aot-runtime.c:2067)
7   LexEAT.iOS                      0x00000001035f64e0 mono_assembly_load_from_predicate + 15131872 (assembly.c:2315)
8   LexEAT.iOS                      0x00000001035f6050 mono_assembly_open_predicate + 15130704 (assembly.c:1972)
9   LexEAT.iOS                      0x000000010370a9f4 xamarin_initialize + 16263668 (runtime.m:943)
10  LexEAT.iOS                      0x000000010371134c xamarin_main + 16290636 (monotouch-main.m:433)
11  LexEAT.iOS                      0x00000001027f4fac main + 446380 (main.m:103)
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001841c856c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018440ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018440ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  SGen worker
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001842f80f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018440ece4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   LexEAT.iOS                      0x00000001036e1f48 thread_func + 16097096 (sgen-thread-pool.c:108)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018440c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018440c180 _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018440ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000036   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x00000001b7761d24
   x12: 0x00000001b7761d24  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0xfffffff011c9925c  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b5432b80  x21: 0x0000000103906000  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b5432c60
   x24: 0x0000000103ff9b34  x25: 0x000000010373cd75  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000001038279b8
   x28: 0x0000000103827998   fp: 0x000000016d676970   lr: 0x000000018440d2f8
    sp: 0x000000016d676940   pc: 0x00000001842f82e8 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

.... etc.

Could this be due to an assembly not being linked? And if so, how do I work out which one?

Comment: When you say it runs fine locally (device and simulator),  Have you actually run your release-built `.ipa` on a local iOS device? (11.2.5 in the case of Apple's test)

Comment: I have run the release-built IPA on an iPhone X running 11.2.6 and it opens fine, it is also fine when testing through TestFlight and was approved for external testing. I had the same thing a couple of weeks ago and although it passed review it would crash for everyone when downloading from the store. At least this time it's being rejected!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?